# Adding dependency causes main class to not be found

Tags: java, gradle

When adding the `com.spotify:docker-client:3.5.12` dependency to build.gradle, it causes my main class "com.gamedash.daemon.Main" to not be found. I have absolutely no clue what this might be causing. Removing the dependency resolves the issue.

`build.gradle`

```
group 'com.gamedash.daemon'
version '0.1'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 9
targetCompatibility = 9

repositories {

    mavenCentral()
    maven {

        url 'https://jetbrains.bintray.com/pty4j'

    }

}

application {

    mainClassName = 'com.gamedash.daemon.Main'

}

jar {

    manifest {

        attributes(

            'Main-Class': 'com.gamedash.daemon.Main'

        )
    }
    from {

        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }

    }

}

sourceSets {

    main {

        resources {

            srcDirs "src/main/resources", "src/main/configs"

        }

    }

}

buildscript {

    repositories {

        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.2.2'

    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation('me.tongfei:progressbar:0.7.4')
    implementation('com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre')
    implementation('com.corundumstudio.socketio:netty-socketio:1.7.17')
    implementation('org.jetbrains.pty4j:pty4j:0.8.6')
    implementation('commons-io:commons-io:2.6')
    implementation('org.zeroturnaround:zt-zip:1.13')
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.8')
    implementation('com.beust:jcommander:1.78')
    implementation('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5')
    implementation('com.github.oshi:oshi-core:4.4.2')
    implementation('net.java.dev.jna:jna:5.3.1')
    implementation('net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:5.3.1')
    implementation('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9')
    implementation('com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.9.1')
    implementation('org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.6')
    implementation('org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5')
    implementation('org.apache.mina:mina-core:2.0.0-M2')
    implementation('org.apache.ftpserver:ftplet-api:1.1.1')
    implementation('org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:1.1.1')
    implementation('org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:2.4.0')
    implementation('org.apache.sshd:sshd-sftp:2.4.0')
    compile('com.spotify:docker-client:3.5.12:shaded')
    implementation('org.beryx:text-io:3.3.0')
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8')
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.8')
    implementation('com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8')
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.4'
    implementation group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.4.0'
    implementation files('lib/icmp4j-all.jar')
    implementation files('lib/Schokker-IT-Rest-Client.jar')
    implementation files('lib/com.gamedash.daemon.common.jar')

}

task obfuscate(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask) {

    configuration 'proguard.txt'
    injars "build/libs/gamedash-daemon-${ version }.jar"
    outjars "build/libs/gamedash-daemon-${ version }-obfuscated.jar"

}
```

Comment: did you run it from IDE or from command line? Can you build the project using gradle?

Comment: @phongnt It builds just fine and I've inspected the JAR that's generated with JD and everything is there in the right place with the right class names. When I run it all it does is Error: Could not find or load main class com.gamedash.daemon.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gamedash.daemon.Main

Comment: did you run with java in command line? the only thing the build step does is to add a file into your jar's MANIFEST, and it's only relevant if you run the jar directly. You could try `java -cp your_lib.jar com.gamedash.daemon.Main`

Comment: @phongnt Nope - that doesn't fix it either. I was already running it from the command line. I've uploaded the JAR here to give you better insight in to why it is happening: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16_3hEvDgqysP-7M0sYJbvgkgOWGsTrrV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Keep in mind that when I remove the com.spotify:docker-client dependency it all works just fine

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the library in question uses Bouncycastle and thus requires a signed jar to run. Would have been much more pleasant if the error message would have said so, instead of telling me that the class was not found.

Fixed it by adding the following rule to my build.gradle

```
exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
```